# Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script. Cannot manage to run this

Tags: reactjs, npm, node-modules, node-sass

I have gone through all the questions regarding this issue but I cannot seem to find anything that works.

I am getting this error :-

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.11.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I have tried to remove the node_modules and npm install again.  I also tried to remove the node-sass folder in the node_modules and npm install -g node-sass@latest did not work too.  I also tried

```
npm install -g node --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

and

```
npm uninstall node-sass
npm cache clean --force
npm install -g node-sass@latest
```

but nothing seems to be working at all.  Is there someone who can shed some light on this please?

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 17):

Unless you're working on some sort of shared project that has strict requirements you can do the following to overcome the issue:

1.) Delete your `package.lock` file - which indicates the versions to be locked at.

2.) Delete your `node_modules` folder which contains all the original installations and C++ binary compilations.

3.) Then `npm install` it all back and `npm rebuild` for good measure.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is documented on the [Node-Sass page in NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass).  Upgrade to Node-Sass v 4.12.0 and it will work with Node 12.

Comment: I did upgrade to Node-Sass v4.12.0 but still did not work

Answer (score 2):

try this command it should work successfully

```
sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass
```

it work for me

Answer (score 1):

Following steps worked for me.

1. Remove node_modules folder.
2. Remove package-lock.json file.
3. Run `sudo npm install -g --unsafe-perm node-sass`
4. Run `npm install` without sudo command.

Answer (score 0):

After battling with this issue for a considerable amount of hours, I downgraded from the Current version of Node (12.8.0) to the LTS (10.16.2) and it finally worked.  So if you are having issues like mine, maybe try to downgrade the node version and it can help you

Comment: But why ? there should be a reason. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is because of your incompatible node version with the node-sass module
by the way node-sass is deprecated.
check this link and select the best version with your node installed
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass

Answer (score 0):

just use following command.

npm update